# How to intercept "this" call in class constructor using ES6 Proxy?

Tags: javascript

I have the following classes

```
class Foo {
  bar = ''

  constructor() {
    this.bar = 'updated 1'
    setTimeout(() =>  this.bar = 'update 2', 1000)
  }
}

class Bar {
  foo = ''

  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'updated 1'
    setTimeout(() =>  this.foo = 'update 2', 1000)
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to patch any unconstructed class and then notified when an update occurs to a property where an "updated" message is logged to the console.

I imagine I'd need to run the constructor through a patching function and construct the output.

```
const PatchedFoo = patch(Foo)
const foo = new PatchedFoo()
// Log "Updated"
// After 1000ms Log "Updated"

const PatchedBar = patch(Bar)
const bar = new PatchedBar()
// Log "Updated"
// After 1000ms Log "Updated"
```

I would expect the above code to output "updated" to the console twice per class.

My current attempts have all failed as I tried to use the `construct` method on the Proxy options, but creating a `new target` meant it was already too late to intercept `this` access.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use *[property getter / setter](https://javascript.info/property-accessors)*, instead of *[Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)*:

```js
class Foo {
  _bar = '';

  constructor(barChangeNotifier) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'bar', {
      set: val => {
        this._bar = val; 
        barChangeNotifier(val);
      },
      get: () => this._bar
    });
    this.bar = 'updated 1';
    setTimeout(() =>  this.bar = 'update 2', 1000);
  }
}
const a = new Foo(val => console.log('New BAR value is', val));
a.bar = 'Update 3'
setTimeout(() => a.bar = 'Update 4', 2000);
```

please note, that `Object.defineProperty()` is before any other code within `constructor`.

I added notifier function which should be passed to constructor.
And as @KooiInc mentioned, setters / getters in ES6 may be provided without `Object.defineProperty()` (but both ways are exactly the same)

Answer (score 0):

Without the [class sugar](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/debunking-fake-classes-in-javascript-78f67a6b5c96) something like this is possible:

```js
function Foo(bar = "") {
  const fooObj =  {
    _bar: bar,
    set bar(value) { 
      this._bar = value; 
      console.log(`${new Date().toLocaleString()}: bar updated to [${value}]`); },
    get bar() {return this._bar}
  }
  return fooObj;
}

const foo = Foo("initial");
console.log(`foo.bar now ${foo.bar}`);
setTimeout(() => foo.bar = "updated!", 1000);
setTimeout(() => foo.bar = "updated again!", 2000);
```

Comment: Is it possible to trigger these events without knowing the starting shape of the class? I have updated my original question to clarify

Comment: I really can't tell you. Maybe a [factory function](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1) can do this for you